# ordered stream with comparator

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Does `getSortedUsers()` always returns an orderd stream of `getUsers()` **independent** of the `getUsers()`-collection type?

```
public Set<User> getUsers(){
    // unordered collection type
    HashSet<User> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(..);
    set.add(..);
    set.add(..);
    return set;
}

// Is the stream only sorted if getUsers() is hold within a sortable collection type?
public Stream<User> getSortedUsers(Comparator<User> comp){
    return getUsers().stream().sorted(comp);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Stream` returned by `getSortedUsers()` will always be sorted, which is guaranteed by the call to `sorted(comp)`. It doesn't matter what's the source of the `Stream`.

Now, if you decide to collect the elements of that `Stream` into some `Collection`, the order may or may not be preserved, depending on which type of `Collection` you choose. If you collect the elements into a `HashSet`, you'll lose the order. If you collect into a `TreeSet`, a `LinkedHashSet` or any `List`, you'll keep the order.

Comment: So `getSortedUsers.forEach()` and `getSortedUsers.forEachOrdered()` behaves equal because the returned stream is ordered. Am i right?

Comment: @nimo23 no. Unlike `forEachOrdered`, `forEach()` is **not** guaranteed to respect the encounter order of the Stream. You'll observe the different behavior if you make the Stream parallel.

Comment: But if I do not use a parallel stream, as the stream is ordered and not parallel, forEach() must return the ordered sequence defined by the comparator. Or?

Comment: @nimo23 yes, in sequential Streams `forEach` should return the elements in the order defined by the comparator.

Comment: For a sequential stream, `forEach` happens to use the encounter order, because it’s the way it has been implemented. But there’s no guaranty in the specification. There’s even an imaginable scenario for it failing. A hypothetical implementation may simply skip the sort operation when the terminal operation is unordered.